# Change / Check permissions (Read, Write,...) for the NETWORK SERVICE account with C#

Tags: c#, permissions, user-accounts

How can I change / check the permissions (Read, Write,...) for a specific folder for the NETWORK SERVICE account with C# porgrammatically ?

Comment: Permissions to what? Files, the Registry, a database, certificates...?

Answer (score 0):

There's no generic "find all permissions that this user has on all objects on this filesystem/system/domain function".

For objects where the ACLs are exposed to .Net framework, they typically expose a "GetAccessControl()" method, from which you can enumerate the AccessRules (via "GetAccessRules()"), and find those rules which apply to NETWORK SERVICE